# C# create list within class properties

Tags: c#, list, scope

I created the following within my class

```
  private List<CreditCardTransaction> _ccTransactions = new List<CreditCardTransaction>();

  public List<CreditCardTransaction> ccTransactions
  {
      get { return _ccTransactions; }
      set { _ccTransactions = value; }
  }
```

Within another public function (in the same class) I attempted to add a value to the list using the following code:

```
  _ccTransactions.Add(new CreditCardTransaction(Convert.ToString(items[0]), Convert.ToString(items[1]), Convert.ToDouble(items[2]), DateTime.Parse(items[3])));
```

However a red wavy line under "_ccTransactions" saying

Error   1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'CreditCardTransactionKeeper.CreditCardTransaction._ccTransactions'

What is the proper way for me to add a new item to the list when I am within a method in the class that defined this list?

Comment: @Philip Rieck is absolutely right. Does it make sense, however, why a static method can't access an instance variable?

Comment: @Esteban Araya: Yes, it makes sense. A static method belongs to the entire class, not a particular instance of it, so since there is no accessible instance far as the static method is concerned, there can't be any instance variables.

Comment: @Anna Lear: I assume Esteban was asking the original poster. He's the one that would need to understand the logic behind the behavior in order to have a truly complete answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't access the non-static field (`_ccTransactions`) inside a static function- by the error, I assume your other function is static.

You need to either make `_ccTransactions` static, make your calling function non-static, or get a reference to an object of that class to access `_ccTransactions` from.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I added the key word static in front of the declaration and that did the trick.